# How to identify unused method in xcode

Tags: objective-c

Visual Studio can tell me the methods that are never called, can XCode do the same? Guess not, since they might be called through selector and the name can be formed on fly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no true idea of "unused method" in Obj-C. Because everything is invoked via message passing, the compiler may not be able to find any call sites that explicitly invoke that message, and yet it's still invoked via runtime methods.

If you want to figure out if a method is unused, you can do a project-wide search for the method name (if it takes multiple arguments, you could just try the most distinctive portion of the name, e.g. if you have `-loadData:MIMEType:textEncodingName:baseURL:` you could search for just `MIMEType:`). This will give you a good idea if there's any *explicit* calls of this method. If you're sure you aren't dynamically constructing method names at runtime, then this may be a method that's never called. But whether or not you can actually be confident in this depends on how complex your project is and how much runtime "magic" you use.

Comment: Another possible way is to comment out the method signature in the header file and see the warnings come rolling in.

Comment: @Paul.s: That works in many cases, but not all. For example, if your method is named the same as another existing method, then anyone calling it on an `id`-typed variable won't trigger a warning.

Comment: Yup this is true I was thinking quick and dirty. I always think it's a shame xcode either doesn't have or I can't find any regex ability. I always have to drop to TextMate when I want to do a through search like this especially if the method doesn't have something nice and fairly rare like `MIMEType`.

Comment: @Paul.s: Xcode has regex searching. Click on the little magnifying glass icon in the project search UI.

Comment: +1 Just for pointing that out. Shame you can't use regex replace (I say whilst hoping that you can point that out to)

Comment: You mean referencing captures in the replace? Just use `\n` syntax, e.g. `foo:\1`.